# I like to ask for a suigestion to pass a parameter to another program via POST but "encrypted"

Tags: php, post, web

I have to call a program that generates PDF and I like to pass as a parameter the ID of a record from a database. This is easy as follows:
   http://domain/pdf/index.php?c=31

The issue I have with this is that the user can guess this "31" is in fact the user id and therefore try another number and get the PDF from another user, This is a privacy concern that I want to avoid. I like to have something like this:
    http://domain/pdf/index.php?c=SeNortjKwUlKyBlwwB0U

Can you share  any idea of a function to code this and decode this that is already tested and works?

I will need in the calling program the codification of the ID and in the PDF the de-codification into the ID.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have edited the answer below and checked. its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use urlencode()

```
$query_string = 'c=' . urlencode(strtr(base64_encode($id), '+/=', '-_,'));
echo '<a href="pdf?' . $query_string . '">';
```

When you have to decode it use

```
base64_decode(strtr(urldecode($_GET('c')), '-_,', '+/='));
```

Answer (score 0):

**ENCODING:**

If you simply want to obfuscate the id, use [base64_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) (and `base64_decode()`.

Example:

```
function base64EncodeURLSafe($string) { 
  return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($string), '+/', '-_'), '='); 
} 

function base64DecodeURLSafe($string) { 
  return base64_decode(str_pad(strtr($string, '-_', '+/'), strlen($string) % 4, '=', STR_PAD_RIGHT)); 
}
```

**ENCRYPT**

For added security, you might want to use [mcrypt_encrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) (and `mcrypt_decrypt()`). However, make sure to `urlencode()` and `urldecode()` the encrypted string in order to "escape" any special characters.

Example:

```
$key = "MY SECRET KEY";

function encryptURLSafe($string) {
  return urlencode(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key)))));
}

function decryptURLSafe($string) {
  return rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), base64_decode(urldecode($string)), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "\0");
}
```

Comment: Grant, thanks four your extended solution. I'll keep it in mind as well.